# How to retrieve a part of a stored procedure's header?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a C# `WinForms` application that manages stored procedures used by different services. What the users see is something like that:

```
exec stored_procedure_name param1, param2, param3
```

And since param1 doesn't mean anything to them (they can't see the stored procedure), I would like to present to them small descriptions of the parameters which are normally saved in the header of the stored procedure.

A typical stored procedure would like:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[stored_procedure_name]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure_name]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/*************************************************************************************
[Procedure Info]
Author = myName
Description = this stored procedure returns results.

**************************************************************************************
[Parameters Info]
@param1 = this is parameter one
@param2 = this is parameter two
@param3 = this is parameter three

**************************************************************************************
[Changes]
2015-06-17  The stored procedure is optimized.

*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stored_procedure_name]
@param1 int,
@param2 nvarchar(20),
@param3 nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SP code here
END
GO
```

From the above, I want to get the descriptions in the Parameters info. I know that I can use the following SQL to retrieve the stored procedure as text/table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpHeader
(
   TEXT NVARCHAR(1000)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpHeader
EXEC sp_helptext 'stored_procedure_name';

SELECT * FROM #tmpHeader

DROP TABLE #tmpHeader
```

Any ideas or suggestions how to proceed from here in order to get the content of the parameters info?
I am also open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using extended properties to store meta-data.  This is much cleaner than parsing the module text.

**EDIT:**
The example below returns all parameters plus descriptions for those parameters with extended properties.  In your code, you can pass the schema and object names as parameters instead of the local variables used here for illustration.

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'Description',
    @value = 'this is parameter one', @level0type = N'Schema',
    @level0name = 'dbo', @level1type = N'Procedure',
    @level1name = 'stored_procedure_name', @level2type = N'Parameter',
    @level2name = '@param1';
  GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'Description',
    @value = 'this is parameter two', @level0type = N'Schema',
    @level0name = 'dbo', @level1type = N'Procedure',
    @level1name = 'stored_procedure_name', @level2type = N'Parameter',
    @level2name = '@param2';
  GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'Description',
    @value = 'this is parameter three', @level0type = N'Schema',
    @level0name = 'dbo', @level1type = N'Procedure',
    @level1name = 'stored_procedure_name', @level2type = N'Parameter',
    @level2name = '@param3';
  GO

DECLARE
      @SchemaName sysname = 'dbo'
    , @ObjectName sysname = 'stored_procedure_name';

SELECT  properties.objtype
      , properties.objname
      , parms.name
      , properties.value
FROM sys.parameters AS parms
LEFT JOIN fn_listextendedproperty('Description', 'Schema', @SchemaName, 'Procedure',
                                @ObjectName, 'Parameter', DEFAULT) AS properties ON
    properties.objname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = parms.name
WHERE
    parms.object_id = OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName));
GO
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion. What if there is a change in the stored procedure and a parameter is either added, removed or edited so it does something else?

Comment: @Apostrofix, just like the comments, the extended properties need to be maintained independently of the parameters themselves.  I'll update my answer such that the query returns all defined parameters and returns NULL for missing parameter descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

This should make the think your looking for.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(definition,CHARINDEX(N'[Parameters Info]',definition),CHARINDEX(N'[',definition,CHARINDEX(N'[Parameters Info]',definition)+1)-CHARINDEX(N'[Parameters Info]',definition))
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('YOUR PROCEDURE!!!')
```

It searches for Parameters Info and goes any further until if finds another header block (beginning with [). You can also specify that it should search for *.

Comment: Good idea, it is much simpler than the direction that I was going to. Is it possible to split the Parameters Info block into separate rows, just as it is in the header?

Comment: Yes this should be doable. I currently haven't the time for a short code. But I would suggest to put those string into a cte, and iterate over it and searching for a carriage return. :-)